# How to check if a file has a digital signature

Tags: certificate, code-signing

I'd like to check programatically if a file has been digitally signed or not.

For the moment, I found a rather obscure [Microsoft code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/example-c-program--verifying-the-signature-of-a-pe-file), that doesn't compile...

Any idea on the subject?

An external tool with command line would also be great, by the way.

Answer (score 42):

The important missing part of the answer mentioning `signtool`, e.g. for DevOps/deployment builds with signing is here:

Yes, with the well known `signtool.exe` you can also find out, if a file is signed. No need to download another tool!

E.g. with the simple line:

```
signtool verify /pa myfile.exe
if %ERRORLEVEL% GEQ 1 echo This file is not signed.
```

(For verbose output, add a `/v` after `/pa`.)

One may ask: Why this is important? I just sign the files (again) which shall be signed and it works.

My objective is to keep builds clean, and don't sign files a second time because not only the date is changed, but the binary is different after that.
Bad for compare tasks.
Business example:
My client has a streamlined automated "dev ops" kind build and post build process. There are multiple sources for different file sets, and at the end all is build, tested and bundled to distribution- and for that some files have to be signed. To guarantee that some files don't leave the unit without being signed, we used to sign all important files found on the media, even if they were already signed.

But this hasn´t been clean enough ! Generally:

1. If we sign a file again, which is already signed, the file date and binary fingerprint changes, and the file looses comparability with it's sources, if it was simply copied.
   (At least if you sign with a timestamp, which we always do and I think is highly recommended.)

This is a severe quality loss, because this file is no longer identical to it's predecessors although the file itself has not changed.

2. If we sign a file again, this also could be a fault when it is a third party file which shouldn't be signed by our company.

You can avoid both by making the signing itself conditional depending on the return code of the preceding `signtool verify` call mentioned.

P.S. 2024: Obviously that this works only for files which contain their signature themselves which should be the case for your own files I assume.

Comment: It doesn't work even for system exe `signtool verify /pa c:\Windows\regedit.exe`

Comment: @Robert not all of the executables in the `%SystemDrive%\Windows` directory have a digital signature [detectable by signtool](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/133661/299416) - when the signature is stored in a [security catalog file](https://blog.didierstevens.com/2008/01/11/the-case-of-the-missing-digital-signatures-tab/), signtool will return 'No signature found'. try on the File Explorer `explorer.exe` in the same directory.

Comment: "this only works if the digital signature is stored in the executable itself". for other executables, use @Kantium's answer below

Answer (score 35):

Download [`Sigcheck`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sigcheck) and use the following command.

```
sigcheck.exe -a -u -e
```

An example of a signed dll

```
File version:   0.0.0.0
Strong Name:    Signed
```

An example of an unsigned dll

```
File version:   0.0.0.0
Strong Name:    Unsigned
```

`Sigcheck` is a command-line utility that shows file version number. Good Luck

Comment: It is from Sysinterlals Suit.

Answer (score 26):

Since PowerShell 5.1, you can use [`Get-AuthenticodeSignature`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-authenticodesignature) to verify the signature of a binary or a PowerShell script.

```
> Get-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath .\MyFile.exe

SignerCertificate                 Status        Path                                                                                   
-----------------                 ------        ----                                                                                   
A59E92E31475F813DDAF41C3CCBC8B78  Valid         MyFile.exe
```

Or

```
> (Get-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath .\MyFile.exe).Status
Valid
```

Comment: Does Get-AuthenticodeSignature has any dependency on Digital signature validity period? Will Status changed to "Not Valid" after "Valid To" is passed?

Answer (score 17):

I found another option (pure .NET code) on the web [here](http://certhelp.ksoftware.net/support/solutions/articles/50357-how-do-i-verify-a-digital-signature-in-c-).

The code is very simple and works.

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string filePath = args[0];

        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File not found");
            return;
        }

        X509Certificate2 theCertificate;

        try
        {
            X509Certificate theSigner = X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile(filePath);
            theCertificate = new X509Certificate2(theSigner);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No digital signature found: " + ex.Message);

            return;
        }

        bool chainIsValid = false;

        /*
         *
         * This section will check that the certificate is from a trusted authority IE
         * not self-signed.
         *
         */

        var theCertificateChain = new X509Chain();

        theCertificateChain.ChainPolicy.RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.ExcludeRoot;

        /*
         *
         * Using .Online here means that the validation WILL CALL OUT TO THE INTERNET
         * to check the revocation status of the certificate. Change to .Offline if you
         * don't want that to happen.
         */

        theCertificateChain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online;

        theCertificateChain.ChainPolicy.UrlRetrievalTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);

        theCertificateChain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.NoFlag;

        chainIsValid = theCertificateChain.Build(theCertificate);

        if (chainIsValid)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Publisher Information : " + theCertificate.SubjectName.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Valid From: " + theCertificate.GetEffectiveDateString());
            Console.WriteLine("Valid To: " + theCertificate.GetExpirationDateString());
            Console.WriteLine("Issued By: " + theCertificate.Issuer);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Chain Not Valid (certificate is self-signed)");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this retrieves the certificate used to sign the file, but it does NOT verify that the file's signature is valid (i.e. if you tamper with the file, this method will still return the original signer, it will not alert you to the fact that the file has been tampered with)

Comment: The X509Certificates and the X509Chain objects need to be properly Disposed. Recommend wrapping them in `using` statements.

Comment: The link you added at the top does not work any longer.

Answer (score 14):

If you need an external tool, you can use signtool.exe.  It is part of the Windows SDK, it takes command line arguments, and you can find out more about it here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387764.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Also you can try to use npm package `sign-check` for that purposes.

This package implements WinVerifyTrust API and has simple usage:

```
npm install -g sign-check

sign-check 'path/to/file'
```

Comment: Doesn't work on Linux. Which isn't very obvious since it looks like just a Javascript package.

Answer (score 0):

Select the `<*>.exe` rightclick >properties. if the file is signed then you will get this tab on the property windows of that file.

[image: property of the file]

Comment: I do not see how this helps to verify "programmatically" if the file is being digitally signed or not :)

Comment: this answer has actually helped me

Comment: Wow, this answer is awful. @JerryGoyal: The presence of a digital signature **does not** mean anything. **MAKE SURE** that it is valid by going to Digital Signatures, select signature, then Details and check that "Digital signature is OK" is shown on top.