# How to check if a file is signed in C#?

Tags: c#, dll, exe, sign

I'm writing a program that need to load a few other files.
is there a way to check if those files are signed or not, without right clicking them and check? I use 300-400 files that change every few days
I need to check DLL/EXE/CAB/OCX/MSI (and maybe also vbs/js)

is there a way to check it?

Comment: Unless you're having a specific problem with this, help has a chance to be scarce other than some referencing links that you could potentially have found personally - please let us know what you have attempted so far.

Comment: @Tigran: Code signing. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537361(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to check if a file has a digital signature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667017/how-to-check-if-a-file-has-a-digital-signature)

Comment: Ok, digital signature stuff, thank you...

Comment: I don't agree that this question is not a real question or not constructive. Closers should read what he is asking for.. it is code signing. Right-clicking and checking the properties of the file is the manual way to see if a file is signed. I do agree that it is a duplicate and I posted the link.

Comment: Check this post, I think this is what you're searching for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667017/how-to-check-if-a-file-has-a-digital-signature

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: He is asking for code signing/digital certificates and how to check if a file is signed.

Comment: @0A0D My point still stands (only now emphasised, given the provided answer.)

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: He obviously does not know how to do it or he wouldn't have asked.

Comment: Hmm, if this is not about digital signature, what is this question about so?

Comment: it is about digital signature.
does 'Assembly.LoadFile("").IsFullyTrusted()'  mean it is signed?

Comment: This question was closed for no good reason, but I posted a relevant solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34200959/1037208

Comment: See this https://crookm.com/journal/2019/verify-signed-executables-in-dotnet/#enums-and-helpers

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Assuming you want to check if a file is Authenticode signed and that the certificate is trusted you can pinvoke to [`WinVerifyTrust`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa388208%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in `Wintrust.dll`.

Below is a wrapper (more or less reproduced [from here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200630020153/http://geekswithblogs.net/robp/archive/2007/05/04/112250.aspx)) that can be called as follows:

```
AuthenticodeTools.IsTrusted(@"path\to\some\signed\file.exe")
```

Where `AuthenticodeTools` is defined as follows:

```
internal static class AuthenticodeTools
{
    [DllImport("Wintrust.dll", PreserveSig = true, SetLastError = false)]
    private static extern uint WinVerifyTrust(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr pgActionID, IntPtr pWinTrustData);
    private static uint WinVerifyTrust(string fileName)
    {

        Guid wintrust_action_generic_verify_v2 = new Guid("{00AAC56B-CD44-11d0-8CC2-00C04FC295EE}");
        uint result=0;
        using (WINTRUST_FILE_INFO fileInfo = new WINTRUST_FILE_INFO(fileName,
                                                                    Guid.Empty))
        using (UnmanagedPointer guidPtr = new UnmanagedPointer(Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof (Guid))),
                                                               AllocMethod.HGlobal))
        using (UnmanagedPointer wvtDataPtr = new UnmanagedPointer(Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof (WINTRUST_DATA))),
                                                                  AllocMethod.HGlobal))
        {
            WINTRUST_DATA data = new WINTRUST_DATA(fileInfo);
            IntPtr pGuid = guidPtr;
            IntPtr pData = wvtDataPtr;
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(wintrust_action_generic_verify_v2,
                                   pGuid,
                                   true);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(data,
                                   pData,
                                   true);
            result = WinVerifyTrust(IntPtr.Zero,
                                    pGuid,
                                    pData);
            
        }
        return result;

    }
    public static bool IsTrusted(string fileName)
    {
        return WinVerifyTrust(fileName) == 0;
    }


}

internal struct WINTRUST_FILE_INFO : IDisposable
{

    public WINTRUST_FILE_INFO(string fileName, Guid subject)
    {

        cbStruct = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WINTRUST_FILE_INFO));

        pcwszFilePath = fileName;



        if (subject != Guid.Empty)
        {

            pgKnownSubject = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Guid)));

            Marshal.StructureToPtr(subject, pgKnownSubject, true);

        }

        else
        {

            pgKnownSubject = IntPtr.Zero;

        }

        hFile = IntPtr.Zero;

    }

    public uint cbStruct;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]

    public string pcwszFilePath;

    public IntPtr hFile;

    public IntPtr pgKnownSubject;



    #region IDisposable Members



    public void Dispose()
    {

        Dispose(true);

    }



    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {

        if (pgKnownSubject != IntPtr.Zero)
        {

            Marshal.DestroyStructure(this.pgKnownSubject, typeof(Guid));

            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(this.pgKnownSubject);

        }

    }



    #endregion

}

enum AllocMethod
{
    HGlobal,
    CoTaskMem
};
enum UnionChoice
{
    File = 1,
    Catalog,
    Blob,
    Signer,
    Cert
};
enum UiChoice
{
    All = 1,
    NoUI,
    NoBad,
    NoGood
};
enum RevocationCheckFlags
{
    None = 0,
    WholeChain
};
enum StateAction
{
    Ignore = 0,
    Verify,
    Close,
    AutoCache,
    AutoCacheFlush
};
enum TrustProviderFlags
{
    UseIE4Trust = 1,
    NoIE4Chain = 2,
    NoPolicyUsage = 4,
    RevocationCheckNone = 16,
    RevocationCheckEndCert = 32,
    RevocationCheckChain = 64,
    RecovationCheckChainExcludeRoot = 128,
    Safer = 256,
    HashOnly = 512,
    UseDefaultOSVerCheck = 1024,
    LifetimeSigning = 2048
};
enum UIContext
{
    Execute = 0,
    Install
};

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]

internal struct WINTRUST_DATA : IDisposable
{

    public WINTRUST_DATA(WINTRUST_FILE_INFO fileInfo)
    {

        this.cbStruct = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WINTRUST_DATA));

        pInfoStruct = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WINTRUST_FILE_INFO)));

        Marshal.StructureToPtr(fileInfo, pInfoStruct, false);

        this.dwUnionChoice = UnionChoice.File;



        pPolicyCallbackData = IntPtr.Zero;

        pSIPCallbackData = IntPtr.Zero;



        dwUIChoice = UiChoice.NoUI;

        fdwRevocationChecks = RevocationCheckFlags.None;

        dwStateAction = StateAction.Ignore;

        hWVTStateData = IntPtr.Zero;

        pwszURLReference = IntPtr.Zero;

        dwProvFlags = TrustProviderFlags.Safer;



        dwUIContext = UIContext.Execute;

    }



    public uint cbStruct;

    public IntPtr pPolicyCallbackData;

    public IntPtr pSIPCallbackData;

    public UiChoice dwUIChoice;

    public RevocationCheckFlags fdwRevocationChecks;

    public UnionChoice dwUnionChoice;

    public IntPtr pInfoStruct;

    public StateAction dwStateAction;

    public IntPtr hWVTStateData;

    private IntPtr pwszURLReference;

    public TrustProviderFlags dwProvFlags;

    public UIContext dwUIContext;



    #region IDisposable Members



    public void Dispose()
    {

        Dispose(true);

    }



    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {

        if (dwUnionChoice == UnionChoice.File)
        {

            WINTRUST_FILE_INFO info = new WINTRUST_FILE_INFO();

            Marshal.PtrToStructure(pInfoStruct, info);

            info.Dispose();

            Marshal.DestroyStructure(pInfoStruct, typeof(WINTRUST_FILE_INFO));

        }



        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pInfoStruct);

    }



    #endregion

}

internal sealed class UnmanagedPointer : IDisposable
{

    private IntPtr m_ptr;

    private AllocMethod m_meth;

    internal UnmanagedPointer(IntPtr ptr, AllocMethod method)
    {

        m_meth = method;

        m_ptr = ptr;

    }



    ~UnmanagedPointer()
    {

        Dispose(false);

    }



    #region IDisposable Members

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {

        if (m_ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
        {

            if (m_meth == AllocMethod.HGlobal)
            {

                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(m_ptr);

            }

            else if (m_meth == AllocMethod.CoTaskMem)
            {

                Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(m_ptr);

            }

            m_ptr = IntPtr.Zero;

        }



        if (disposing)
        {

            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);

        }

    }



    public void Dispose()
    {

        Dispose(true);

    }



    #endregion



    public static implicit operator IntPtr(UnmanagedPointer ptr)
    {

        return ptr.m_ptr;

    }

}
```

Comment: Also see http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wintrust.winverifytrust for other interop notes about the `WinVerifyTrust` function.

Comment: FWIW there is an excellent purely .NET library for this now https://github.com/vcsjones/AuthenticodeExaminer

Comment: @VivekRathod Nice find, but I take exception to the term "purely .NET library". [*"The library is a wrapper around native Windows APIs that provide this functionality."*](https://github.com/vcsjones/AuthenticodeExaminer#authenticode-examiner)

Comment: @spender agreed - I used the term rather incorrectly as you pointed out.