# Software Integrity Test C# dll

Tags: c#, dll, checksum, integrity

I wrote a C# class Library (.dll) wish as you know does not use a Main() but I am using  to be used with a Web Application and PreApplicationStart in assemblyinfo.cs gets called. How can I do a software integrity test or do a internal check sum or the dll to make sure it has not change using HMAC SHA or SHA sum? I've done this with c program but not sure how with C# library.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537364%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596327/how-to-check-if-a-file-is-signed-in-c/6597017#6597017

Comment: Why? Regular .Net strong signing will give you most of protection you *can* get with no effort on your side...

Comment: I need to prove in some documentation that the file has not been tampered and is part of an integrity test for cryptographic software module..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this was just a misunderstanding what .NET provides as mechanism to verify a dynamic library link file (DLL). Thanks for the comments. I will close this question.

This article is a bit older but got me the answer I was looking for as I am uitilizing GAC and assembly in web application.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/xwb8f617%28v=vs.100%29.aspx