# Verify Authenticode of an exectuable with C# .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, signtool, authenticode

We deliver an executable to a client-service which starts this executable in a new process after downloading it from our servers.

The executable is signed (authenticode) with the CodeSigning-Certificate of our company and now i'd like to verify, that the downloaded executable is validly signed with this CodeSigning-Certificate to prevent malicious Man-in-the-middle attacks.

But currently i can't find any hints on how to verify this without using "signtool.exe" (which isn't available on the client).

The Download-Service on the client is a .NET 4.0 application written in C#. So i'm searching for a way, to verify the authenticode of the downloaded file and only proceed, if the verification succeeded.

Comment: You need to p/invoke WinVerifyTrust: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596327/how-to-check-if-a-file-is-signed-in-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this question is from 2015 and I assume you can **use .NET Standard 2.0**, there is another option available:

##### You can use the NuGet Package [Microsoft.Security.Extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Security.Extensions):

```cs
using Microsoft.Security.Extensions;

...

using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(@"c:\test.exe"))
{
    FileSignatureInfo sigInfo = FileSignatureInfo.GetFromFileStream(fs);

    Console.WriteLine(sigInfo.State); // SignatureState.SignedAndTrusted
}
```

###### Important:

Make sure, that you add `getfilesiginforedistwrapper.dll` and the corresponding native dll of your platform! (`getfilesiginforedist.dll`)

###### Source:

I've had a look how Microsoft does this for the PowerShell cmdlet `Get-AuthenticodeSignature` [and found it there](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/d29f34b5c278956ccc6e152d0b8104ed898f3511/src/System.Management.Automation/security/Authenticode.cs#L304-L375)

##### Alternatives:

- The native [WinVerifyTrust()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows/win32/get-information-authenticode-signed-executables) apis (There are other answers available which cover that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6597017)

Comment: Thanks for your answer to this long standing question. I was unable to verify your solution, since the project is long gone. But since it is used inside powershell, i mark this as the answer. :)

Comment: @kapsiR Good Find! It helped. Just adding my two cents.

- The api works only on windows 10 and higher. It is not working on windows 7 with dotnetcore. It throws dll not found exception. 

- The library is not disposing the signatures and the `FileSignatureInfo` class does not exposing Dispose. So we have to manually dispose the certificates

`fileSignatureInfo?.SigningCertificate?.Dispose();`
`fileSignatureInfo?.TimestampCertificate?.Dispose();`