# Verifying Authenticode with a self-signed certificate

Tags: digital-signature, code-signing, self-signed, authenticode

If I have a self-signed certificate that is not in the machine's trusted root certificate store, how can I verify that a PE file is Authenticode-signed using that certificate without adding that certificate to the trusted root store?

C# would be preferred, but an answer in C++ is fine, too.

There are many similar questions already on StackOverflow, but none so far has an answer that is acceptable.  It **must** be Authenticode, and I **cannot** add it to the certificate store.  It also cannot be a purchased certificate, because it needs a longer validity time (irrespective of timestamping).

Other than to copy a huge chunk of the Mono signature check code, I don't know of a solution in Win32 or .NET.

Comment: Certificate and signature validation are tricky subjects; a lot needs to be checked. I'm not sure if there is a shortcut.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes But is there a way to accomplish this with the Microsoft APIs?

Comment: Undoubtedly. C++ and .NET are Turing complete. If I knew an easy way or tool to do it then I would certainly have answered (just like the other 7 people that voted up, undoubtedly).

Comment: Without the certificate store or any other trusted certificate you can never validate a certificate.  If you ignore the chain root, then **any** self-signed certificate would be valid, thus allowing anyone to create a valid signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with calling [`Get-AuthenticodeSignature`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-authenticodesignature?view=powershell-7.3) PowerShell cmdlet checking `.Status` is `Valid` or `NotTrusted` and verifying that `.SignerCertificate` is actually yours certificate. If you want more customized solution consider inspecting corresponding DLL sources [Authenticode.cs](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/a1349e331ef2b8ed917475981c857dabe1a2d2c0/src/System.Management.Automation/security/Authenticode.cs). See also a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75291260/5647513).