# Check if executable is signed using C#

Tags: c#, windows, windows-7, sha1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to check if a file has a digital signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667017/how-to-check-if-a-file-has-a-digital-signature)

I want to implement sigcheck like functionality using C#. As per my understanding C# donot have classes for this functionality and I will have to port 
WinVerifyTrust() as well as  CryptCATAdminCalcHashFromFileHandle().

Is anyone of you have already done this porting? or Can you suggest any other alternative to check if file is signed?

Appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Comment: [Here](http://geekswithblogs.net/robp/archive/2007/05/04/112250.aspx)'s a fairly old article that might help.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit :** Its a duplicate of an old question on SO. This should have been a comment which I dint know at the time of posting. Just wanted to relink that his answers are already out there on SO. This is not an answer but only a reference to the old questions which are answered that are the same to this.

There is Wintrust.dll. So you need not port but you can PInvoke WinVerifyTrust() from it as does CryptCATAdminCalcHashFromFileHandle or any other function from the dll.

[relink to a previous question of the same type.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596327/how-to-check-if-a-file-is-signed-in-c)

[one more on the same topic.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667017/how-to-check-if-a-file-has-a-digital-signature)

Comment: He mentions `WinVerifyTrust()` in his question. I'm pretty sure he knows it needs to be implemented.

Comment: Good job finding the duplicate.  But usually we mention those in comments, not answers.

Comment: @M.Babcock yes, ofcourse. But he can invoke them from the dll. It is a duplicate of two other questions from the SO already.

Comment: @King - Which means you likely won't see upvotes. Links are not answers so this probably should have been a comment.

Comment: @BenVoigt Oh. I dint know how to link the question to a previous question. So added it in answer. Is there way to link this question to the previous question.

Comment: @M.Babcock I don't want votes my friend. I just want to tell the OP that his answers are already there. Dint know that it should be in comment. Tried to see if I can link it to a previous question like in many other sites. I couldn't find such feature. So I added. Yes, should be a comment. Will follow hereafter.

Comment: @King: To put a link in a comment, put the link caption inside square brackets, and the link URL inside parentheses right afterward.  Like `[click here](http://www.stackoverflow.com/)` becomes [click here](http://www.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @King - If you find a duplicate it is usually best to post a comment notifying the asker and then flag it as such.

Comment: @M.Babcock: He doesn't yet have enough reputation to vote to close as duplicate.

Comment: @BenVoigt - My mistake. The comment should be enough then.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Will follow them :)

Comment: Eventually, you'll accumulate enough reputation to vote to close questions as duplicates. That will automagically insert the comment you've probably seen all over the place, just like Ben's above on the question. Until then, when you want to suggest a duplicate, you can manually leave a comment. Other users with close vote privileges will see it, and if they agree, cast close votes of their own. You can also use the "flag" link to suggest a question as a duplicate, which ensures that people will notice it. This is especially useful for old questions that people might not happen across.

Comment: Using only WinVerifyTrust() doesn't work. I think We need to use unmanged code from here. http://forum.sysinternals.com/howto-verify-the-digital-signature-of-a-file_topic19247.html I have limited skills in interop, can anyone please help?

Comment: @user1136789 - Feel free to open a separate question to ask any questions specific to any impedances you encounter. This question will likely end up being closed as a duplicate anyway. And note that the question comment I posted above includes an example of doing what you're asking.

Comment: @M.Babcock: I tried the example for your link but it is not fully functional. It returns false for the signed file detected by sigcheck tool. I think it is missing the catelogContext calculation.

Comment: @user1136789 check this[c# digital signature](http://geekswithblogs.net/robp/archive/2007/05/04/112250.aspx)

Comment: @king: its the same thing. It returns false for signed files.