# Validating a Code Signing Certificate on a Windows Application

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to programmatically validate a code signing certificate as described in [this question from 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24060009/checking-digital-signature-on-exe/24064112).  After following the suggestions, I am still not able to find a consistent working solution to determine when my .exe has been tampered with (i.e. the hash no longer matches)

The `WinVerifyTrust` method from `wintrust.dll` is the most accurate however I seem to getting a false positive after my executable has been obfuscated/VM'd.  In this scenario, I am getting a result of (int)2148204800 even though the .exe is validly signed and un-tampered with.  I am also averse to using Windows API calls as I want the code to be as portable as possible.

The other methods such as `X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile().Verify()` and the Powershell method of course do not validate the exe's hash so return true.

Is there any new way that's come about in the last 4 years to validate the hash of the .exe, preferably in pure .NET?  I am happy with a solution that simply validates that the hash and not the entire certificate (if that's possible).

Comment: "Is there any new way that's come about in the last 4 years to validate the hash of the .exe, preferably in pure .NET?" - Unfortunately no. Can you post your C# code that is doing what I assume is platform invoke?

Comment: I am using the code verbatim from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596327/how-to-check-if-a-file-is-signed-in-c/6597017#6597017

Comment: “I seem to getting a false positive after my executable has been obfuscated/VM'd.” That's a claim with not enough details.

Comment: @LexLi I didn't want the obfuscation method to be the focal point of the discussion. The takeaway point as I see it is that WinVerifyTrust is returning a generic error code even though 1) The .exe is fully signed and untampered with, 2) The .exe is fully readable/accessible and 3) Windows 'Properties'->Digital Signatures shows the signature is valid. 4) The X509Certificate.Verify method is still working as well.  I absolutely need certainty on the return of this method since it will be used to stop the application if the signature is bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the WinVerifyTrust API.

A largish working class with PInvoke calls too long to post here, is available at [PInvoke.net: WinVerifyTrust](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wintrust.WinVerifyTrust). You can copy that code verbatim and call `WinTrust.VerifyEmbeddedSignature()` to verify the signature and file hash.

Additionally, it's also a good idea to check the certificate (first) to make sure it's the **correct certificate**. Somebody could change the file, then sign with a new certificate.

To put it together:

- Check the certificate
- Use the WinTrust helper

```cs
var theSigner = X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile(filePath);
var theCertificate = new X509Certificate2(theSigner);

// ensure it's my application's cerfificate
var subject = theCertificate.Subject;
if (!subject.Contains("ACME Inc.")
    return false;

// verify the authenticode signature and file hash
if (WinTrust.VerifyEmbeddedSignature(filePath))
    return true;

return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pull from Mono.Security as a Nuget Package they have a nice `AuthenticodeDeformatter` class that will verify code signing certificates:

```
var authenticode = new AuthenticodeDeformatter(Filename);
authenticode.IsTrusted(); //Should return False if tampered with.
```

Comment: Does this actually validate the Authenticode signature? This looks like all it is doing is validating the certificate in the executable, but not that the executable is signed correctly with the certificate.

Comment: Apologies I picked the wrong routine. See updated reply.

Comment: Thanks for the updated code.  Giving it a go now and will update you soon.

Comment: Update: I just Installed the Mono.Security NuGet Package and tried your code.  I am consistently getting a 'false' on IsTrusted (Reason code 1, no digital signature), even though Windows properties clearly tells me there is a SHA1 & SHA265 valid digital signature on the specified file.  Confusingly, the code returns the same result if I put a non-existent filename.  I am sure that the specified path-name is correct (including matching case).  Not sure what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Update #2: In the same test code, I put in X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile(filename).Verify() and can see the certificate.  When AuthenticodeDeformatter(filename) executes in the same block of code, I cannot see any certificates loaded (still Result=1).  For the record, this code is being run outside of the executable in question and I have not obfuscated the resulting .exe, only signed it.  I am trying to build the Mono Security dll from its source to see if I can trace the problem, however it looks like trying to do that is another StackOverflow question  ;)

Comment: Update #3: Unfortunately never managed to get the code to work even on a generic Microsoft-signed DLL.  I tried the two Nuget versions that were available and they both didn't detect the certificate.  I also had to give up trying to debug the Mono.Security code as I couldn't figure out how to compile it.