# C# active program identification

Tags: c#

I am currently working on a programmable keyboard, based on an Arduino. The C# program gets the information which key is pressed via USB. Until now I am able to open programs, using shortcuts, ...

As an addition I want to have different key-bindings for different programs.
To get this working I have to get a specific detail from the active program, like the name of the exe file.

While searching I have found out, that I can get the active window with the `GetActiveWindow` function and I know, that I have to use another Windows function, but I haven't found out which one.

I was able to get the header text of the window, but this text was for example different for each open Word document, so I couldn't use this.

Anyone have a clue which function I can use, to get something specific to compare with an if statement, like this:

```
string activeProgram;
...
if(activeProgram=="Word"){...}
else if(activeProgram=="Chrome"){...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using [`GetActiveWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646292(v=vs.85).aspx) you have a Window Handle (hWnd).

You can use it to get a Process Id by calling [`GetWindowThreadProcessId`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522(v=vs.85).aspx).

This is the P/Invoke declaration:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint processId);
```

Once you have a Process Id, you need to find the executable.

If you were to continue using the windows API... you can do that with [`GetModuleFileNameEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683198(v=vs.85).aspx), [`GetProcessImageFileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683217(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`QueryFullProcessImageName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684919(v=vs.85).aspx). You would need to use [`OpenProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320(v=vs.85).aspx) to get a Process Handle (hProcess).

Although, there is no need to. Once you have a Process Id you can get the executable file using [`Process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var process = Process.GetProcessById((int)processId);
var fileName = process.MainModule.FileName;
```

Note: the security restriction still apply. Your program will need to have the required privileges to read the other process and get the file name.

---

With that, you can get the main executable file of the process that created the active window. Although, what if a malicious user has renamed an executable something else to trick your program? - Bonus chatter: [how to check if a file has a digital signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667017/how-to-check-if-a-file-has-a-digital-signature).

Comment: The code is working so far and i get the full path of my file (this is something i can really good work with, thank you), but the problem is, when i want to get the name of another window, i get an Win32 exception, because i can´t access a 64bit process with a 32bit process. Can i make my own file a 64bit program? Or is there another way?

Comment: @Schiep first make sure you are not casting between IntPtr and int. You need to declare [`GetActiveWindow` to return IntPtr](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getactivewindow). Second, you may need to configure compile targets for 32 bits and 64 bits (under Build -> Configuration Manager). See [64-bit Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241064.aspx) on msdn. The article [Considerations for porting existing .NET (C#) applications to 64-bit](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGSMK_7.1.1/development_sym/app_net_port_64bit.html) may help (ignore Symphony).